# Looking for a way to identify tests to deprecate/remove based on code changes

Tags: automated-testing, test-management, test-automation-framework

How do companies do this typically? Is there any metadata linkage between test cases and code components covered?

Comment: There are no magical metadata in the sky - only the one you will create. There are many ways to create such metadata. It is interesting question but needs some work to survive, otherwise could be closed as too wide and too opinion-based.

Answer (score 0):

> How do companies do this typically?

In the past I've used checkin comments as input to the process.

But there's nothing simple or automatic about it. They are simply clues as to which tests might need to be revised or deprecated.